# Salesforce SSL Cert imported into java trust store for integration works on the day imported but gives certificate error the next day

Tags: authentication, java, bulk-api, jwt, ssl

I am importing the Salesforce SSL certs for the test.salesforce.com and our sandbox environment using the commands below in a VM server environment.

#### Import test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com cert based on the box being hit

1. java -jar InstallCert.jar test.salesforce.com
2. keytool -exportcert -alias test.salesforce.com-1 -keystore jssecacerts -storepass changeit -file testsalesforcecom.cer
3. C:/Software/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file testsalesforcecom.cer

#### Import sandbox specific cert (Example SIT)

1. java -jar InstallCert.jar sandbox-domain.my.salesforce.com
2. keytool -exportcert -alias sandbox-domain.my.salesforce.com-1 -keystore jssecacerts -storepass changeit -file sitsalesforce.cer
3. keytool -importcert -alias  sandbox-domain.my.salesforce.com -keystore C:/Software/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file sitsalesforce.cer

Importing the certificates for the urls works the current day but next day the outbound bulk api authentication call fails with a certificate path error:
Exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Are we importing the correct SSL cert to add to the trust store? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi @ShreyasD, I have a similar issue. I'm unable to conenct to my trial enterprise org from a local application (Still in development). How do I resolve this? What is the InstallCert.jar? Can you pls provide some details?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a SSL Inspection proxy on the firewall that created a dummy certificate daily for all communications outbound to Salesforce.com. The resolution was to whitelist all domains *.salesforce.com to bypass the SSL proxy.